# ReactJS iterate through state array with dynamic key with its data

Tags: reactjs, state, react-state-management, react-state

I have a array like:

```
"data": {
    "key1": {
        "key_val1": "data1",
        "key_val2": "data2",
        "key_val3": "data3",
        "key_val4": "data4",

    },
    "key2": {
        "key_val1": "data1",
        "key_val2": "data2",
        "key_val3": "data3",
        "key_val4": "data4",

    },
    "key3": {
        "key_val1": "data1",
        "key_val2": "data2",
        "key_val3": "data3",
        "key_val4": "data4",

    }
}
```

I want to iterate with this array and populate my table, but I am getting error **this.state.data.map() is not a function**.

Here is my react component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import $ from "jquery";
import axios from "axios";

class DataComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    data: [],
    isLoading: true
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData() {
    var curr_date = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
    const params = new FormData();
    params.append("date", curr_date);
    axios
      .post(`http://api.mydomain.in/getdataList/`, params)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.data.result === 1) {
          this.setState({
            data: res.data.data,
            isLoading: false
          });
        }
        if (!this.state.isLoading) {
          this.initTable();
        }

      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  initTable() {
    $("#my_table").DataTable({
      bLengthChange: false,
      lengthMenu: [[15, 15, 15, "All"]],
      language: {
        search: "_INPUT_",
        searchPlaceholder: "Search records"
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="tab-pane active" id="mytab">
        <div className="inner-content table-responsive">
          <table id="my_table" className="display" style={{ width: "100%" }}>
            <thead>
              <tr className="heading-table">
                <th>Col1</th>
                <th>col2 </th>
                <th>col3 </th>
                <th>col4 </th>
                <th>col5 </th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            {this.state.isLoading ? null : (
              <tbody>
                {this.state.data.map(d => (
                  <tr>
                    <td>{d}</td>
                    <td>{d.key_val1}</td>
                    <td>{d.key_val2}</td>
                    <td>{d.key_val3}</td>
                    <td>{d.key_val4}</td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            )}
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DataComponent;
```

`this.state.data` will be updated with the sample array as shown above.

How can I achieve this?
I have also tried with `Object.keys(this.state.data).map()`, but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `data` variable is a JSON object, not an array. To convert it to an array and get both the keys and values, you can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

This function will return an array containing other arrays with the key as your first value, and the value as the second :

```
{Object.entries(this.state.data).map(([key, value]) => (
    <tr key={key}>
        <td>{key}</td>
        <td>{value.key_val1}</td>
        <td>{value.key_val2}</td>
        <td>{value.key_val3}</td>
        <td>{value.key_val4}</td>
    </tr>
))}
```

If you do not need the keys of your object, you can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values).

An alternative using deconstruction :

```
{Object.entries(this.state.data).map(([key, { key_val1, key_val2, key_val3, key_val4 }]) => (
    <tr key={key}>
        <td>{key}</td>
        <td>{key_val1}</td>
        <td>{key_val2}</td>
        <td>{key_val3}</td>
        <td>{key_val4}</td>
    </tr>
))}
```

Another version using nested mapping, that will work with any kind of objects :

```
{Object.entries(this.state.data).map(([key, value]) => (
    <tr key={key}>
        <td>{key}</td>
        {Object.entries(value).map(([name, data]) => <td key={name} >{data}</td>)}
    </tr>
))}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is happening because you're trying to pull elements from an array that does not yet have any data through `this.state.data.map()` During the initial render, your component state does not have any data in it yet and your `getData()` method does not run until AFTER the initial render. You could do a quick initial check to see if your state has data before executing `this.state.data.map` like so

```
{this.state.data ? this.state.data.map(d => (
        <tr>
            <td>{d}</td>
            <td>{d.key_val1}</td>
            <td>{d.key_val2}</td>
            <td>{d.key_val3}</td>
            <td>{d.key_val4}</td>
        </tr>
  )) : null }
```

Comment: Yes, because of this I have used `this.state.isLoading`. Initially the value is true, and the `this.state.data.map` would not be executed. I am making it false when the `this.state.data` has been populated with the api call.